# Why Does This Python Function Print Twice?

Tags: python

I'm not able to walk through as to why this code prints 'spam' twice.

```
def do_twice(f):
    f()
    f()

def print_spam():
    print('spam')

do_twice(print_spam)
```

Comment: Erm, because you call the function twice inside do_twice?

Comment: ... `do_twice` calls the input function (`print_spam`) two times.  Each time `print_spam` is called, it prints `'spam'` ...

Comment: What else would you expect to happen? If you do something twice, it gets done twice.

Comment: "this function did exactly what I told it to do. why did it do that?" basically...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's split your code...

**Part1**: create function `do_twice(f)`, that will run `f()` two times.

```
def do_twice(f):
    f()
    f()
```

**Part2**: create a function called `print_spam()` that will `print()` the word `"spam"`

```
def print_spam():
    print('spam')
```

**Part3**: call the function `print_spam()` inside the `do_twice()` funtion

```
do_twice(print_spam)
```

This way, your code will 'think' something like this:

"Oh he called `do_twice(print_spam)`! Now I must run `print_spam()` two times, since `print_spam()` replaces the `f()` role."

Answer (score 1):

`do_twice(print_spam)` calls `print_spam` twice, and `print_spam` prints out `'spam'`, so that's why the code prints it out twice

Answer (score 1):

`print_spam` is a function object being passed in do_twice function. You are calling the function object with `function_object()`

Answer (score 1):

It's just about how you order the code in your mind to understand better:

```
#Intermediate function right here

def do_twice(f):
               f()
               f()

#Function Definition Right here
def print_spam():
               print('spam')


#calling the (actual) function  which in turn calls the intermediate function
do_twice(print_spam)
```

So, as you go about calling the (actual) function once, your intermediate function
in turn, gets called twice and then prints 'spam' twice.